# C++ mciSendString()

Tags: c++, audio

I've written a game in c++ and am playing the audio with

`mciSendString("play sounds/music.wav repeat", NULL, 0, NULL);`.

Now, on the computers at my university (Windows 7 , not sure if 32 or 64-bit) it plays fine but on my home pc (Windows 7 64-bit) I get no sound. How is this possible? I have heard that the MCI drivers are not included in windows 7, so how come it plays fine on a windows 7 computer at my university but not on my home pc? I'm using Devc++ and before anyone mentions how awful it is (I know), I have to use as it is a requirement for my game.

Comment: mciSendString() returns an error code.  You don't check it so you don't know why it failed.  Nor do we.

Comment: Fair point. How would I check the error?

Comment: @omegaFlame: like Hans said, `mciSendString()` returns an error code, which is of type `MCIERROR`. The possible values are [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757153.aspx).

Comment: Yeah thanks, how would I display this error code? I'm not familiar with c++ and the windows API as I mostly use Java.

Answer (score 1):

In your line of code:

```
mciSendString("play sounds/music.wav repeat", NULL, 0, NULL);
```

There are no double quotation marks, this is the problem. Any multimedia device doesn't recognize this command line.
The correct syntax is to put your path and audio file (sounds/music.wav) inside double quotation marks. This line of code should work:

```
mciSendString("play \"sounds/music.wav\" repeat", NULL, 0, NULL);
```

Of course you need to write the '\' character in order to write quotation mark character ' " ' inside string value.

Change your old line of code to this. If it still not working, so you should call mciGetErrorString function and find out why the command is not carried out, and what you have to do to solve your problem.